# Showing different views from each button

Tags: swiftui

New to SwiftUI, so forgive my ignorance.

I have several buttons in an HStack. I want each button to show a different view. My button code looks like this:

```
HStack {
    Button(action: { showSheet.toggle() } ) {
        Image("one")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
        OneView(showSheet: $showSheet)
    }
    Button(action: { showSheet.toggle() } ) {
        Image("two")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
        TwoView(showSheet: $showSheet)
    }
    Button(action: { showSheet.toggle() } ) {
        Image("three")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
        ThreeView(showSheet: $showSheet)
    }
    Button(action: { showSheet.toggle() } ) {
        Image("four")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
        FourView(showSheet: $showSheet)
        }
}
```

I also have this at the top-level view:

```
@State private var showSheet = false
```

Here is the problem: It doesn't matter which button I click, it shows OneView. I also tried adding .sheet... inside each button view like this:

```
Button(action: { showSheet.toggle() } ) {
    Image("one")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                OneView(showSheet: $showSheet)
        }
}
```

But the same behavior happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use *one* `sheet` modifier and use the `sheet(item:)` from instead of `sheet(isPresented:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use different var names for each view. Or an **array**:

```swift
@State private var showSheet = Array(repeating: false, count: 5)
//                                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
//                                    ^ we want the array start from 1 
//                                    so we add 0 at the first.
```

Use:

```swift
HStack {
    Button(action: { showSheet[1].toggle() } ) {
        Image("one")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet[1]) {
        OneView(showSheet: $showSheet[1)
    }
    Button(action: { showSheet[2].toggle() } ) {
        Image("two")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet[2]) {
        TwoView(showSheet: $showSheet[2])
    }
    Button(action: { showSheet[3].toggle() } ) {
        Image("three")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet[3]) {
        ThreeView(showSheet: $showSheet[3])
    }
    Button(action: { showSheet[4].toggle() } ) {
        Image("four")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet[4]) {
        FourView(showSheet: $showSheet[4])
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked great and helped me understand how views work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you look at

```
@State private var showSheet = false
```

And

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) { OneView(showSheet: $showSheet) }
```

As well as this inside any of your button actions

```
showSheet.toggle()
```

What this means is when the showSheet variable is toggled, it will trigger the .sheet modifier and present an instance of OneView, which becomes an issue because the showSheet variable can only trigger one sheet at a time which is the first one in your SwiftUI code, so what you need to do is have different variables to handle different sheet presentations, like this:

```
@State private var showSheetOne = false
@State private var showSheetTwo = false
@State private var showSheetThree = false
@State private var showSheetFour = false
```

And on each .sheet modifier, you want to individually set the bindings and toggle each one in it's respective button

```
HStack {
    Button(action: { showSheetOne.toggle() } ) {
        Image("one")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheetOne) {
        OneView(showSheet: $showSheetOne)
    }
    Button(action: { showSheetTwo.toggle() } ) {
        Image("two")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheetTwo) {
        TwoView(showSheet: $showSheetTwo)
    }
    Button(action: { showSheetThree.toggle() } ) {
        Image("three")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheetThree) {
        ThreeView(showSheet: $showSheetThree)
    }
    Button(action: { showSheetFour.toggle() } ) {
        Image("four")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheetFour) {
        FourView(showSheet: $showSheetFour)
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution also worked but Ii went with the one above only because the result was slightly shorter. Thanks!